# What is the fastest way to determine if a value is in a set of values in Java?

Tags: java, set, exists

This is probably a simple question for you JAVA experts, but I'm relatively new, so I thought I'd ask.  I need to test if string X exists in a set.  I don't need any associated values or indices, and I don't need any order.  I just need to know if it exists.  I know that this could be implemented using a HashMap or ArrayList, but those seem overkill.  What to do?  Just a List?  Or is there something even more basic that would serve the same purpose.  What is the fastest way to test if some string X exists in a given set?

Comment: How big is the set? You can't be sure of the fastest solution without benchmarking it with realistic data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("foo");
set.add("bar");

boolean no = set.contains("baz");
boolean yes = set.contains("foo");
```

There are other `Set` implementations available, of course, but `HashSet` is probably the most appropriate here.

Comment: we actually used almost same string names ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have just `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, JDK comes with a good variety of classes, in which you can find also what you are looking for: sets.

One of them for example is `HashSet`, which has the functionality you are looking about..

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

set.add("foo");
set.add("bar");

boolean b = set.contains("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

...

if (Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz").contains(myString)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This won't be efficient, since it will be O(N) compared with an `HashSet` (constant O(1) ) or a `TreeSet` (I guess O(logn) if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Jack for very small sets (say, <5) it will be as efficient, and easier to write. Of course it is not a general solution, but the questioner thinks the general solution is "overkill" anyway.

Comment: You are both right - but the OP needs to benchmark with an appropriate size of set!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this could be implemented using a HashMap or ArrayList, but those seem overkill.

What exactly is "overkill" about using a builtin class that is *designed* to do exactly what you want, and do it very fast? Because that's what `HashMap` is. `HashSet` would be a bit more basic in its interface (not mapped values), but it's actually implements by having a `HashMap` with null values.

Comment: Well, `HashMap` is designed to map keys to values, which is *more* than the OP wants (as he only needs "presence"). `HashSet`, on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

Several answers have suggested `HashSet`, and others have pointed out that simpler collections might be faster for small sets - you haven't said what size of set.

The size of the Strings is also relevant, because `HashSet` etc will use the hashcode of the String, which is computed from the entire contents of the String (and then cached). This might take a little time - but on the other hand it may have already been computed, depending on your code, so wouldn't incur an extra cost.

In some cases you may be able to rule out Strings from the set by their size, or by checking the first few characters - it depends on your data and your set of Strings. A data structure such as a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) could be useful here - (but you wanted a simple solution).

If performance is critical, then you need to benchmark all the suggested solutions carefully under realistic conditions. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

If you really need a fast solution (is this actually critical for your application?) then you may need to tolerate 'overkill' !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use contains use **Collections.binarySearch(List, Object)**

Don't forget to sort before you use this method **Collections.sort(List)**